# Chrome WebUSB not recognizing devices (CAC cards, smart cards)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have made a script to load all of the USB devices connected to Chrome using `chrome.usb.getDevices`. So far, it has listed a second-generation iPod touch as well as a mouse, keyboard, and two unknown items from Intel. However, it has not recognized any USB flash drives, and it does not recognize any Smart Cards that I have. I've also installed Chrome's Smart Card Connector app into Chrome, but I can still not get Chrome to recognize these Smart Cards. I can't continue to use Java nor ActiveX to for smartcard interactions in the browser. How can I get CAC/smartcard authentication through the browser without having to install a slew of other dependencies?

Edit: I also installed WinUSB as their drivers in place of their default HID drivers, but the results remained.

Answer (score 2):

This [Chrome USB Devices](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#caveats) states that not all USB devices are supported and can be read:

**Caveats**

> Not all devices can be accessed through the USB API. In general,
>   devices are not accessible because either the Operating System's
>   kernel or a native driver holds them off from user space code. Some
>   examples are devices with HID profiles on OSX systems, and USB pen
>   drives.
>
> On most Linux systems, USB devices are mapped with read-only
>   permissions by default. To open a device through this API, your user
>   will need to have write access to it too. A simple solution is to set
>   a udev rule. Create a file /etc/udev/rules.d/50-yourdevicename.rules
>   with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="[yourdevicevendor]", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
```